# ZF2 segmented route constraint regex

Tags: php, regex, routes, zend-framework2, uri

I am working on a ZF2 application where I need a route like this:

```
'storage-deliver' => array(
    'type' => 'Segment',
    'options' => array(
        'route' => '/storage/:uuid/:path',
        'constraints' => array(
            'uuid' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-]*',
            'path' => '[a-zA-Z0-9-_\./\+]*'
        ),
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'StorageController',
            'action' => 'deliver',
        )
    )
)
```

The route should be able to match any route behind the `uuid` constraint.

Examples:

```
/storage/0e529c8b-2403-40c1-a5bf-c6819e992079/some.file
/storage/0e529c8b-2403-40c1-a5bf-c6819e992079/an/undefined/depth/path/to/some.file
```

I know that the uuid constraint is not correct, but that is not relevant for my problem right now. Problem is the defined constraint `path`. It should be able to match whatever the rest of the given url looks like.

So far the given definition `[a-zA-Z0-9-_\./\+]*` works (at least for the examples I use), but I am pretty sure that there is a way to get that done in a much better way (and a way that truly matches all valid possibilities!).

Somewhere else here I found the following route example:

```
/storage/:uuid/:path{-}
```

First everything was looking good, but `path` did not match in all cases.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: If path must match anything, replace the pattern with `.*`, or `.+`, or (if there should be anything but `/`) - `[^/]*`

Comment: Nice! Works as expected. First I tried `[\s\S]*` which also works, but `.*` seems to be much clearer. Thanks for that. Convert your comment into an answer and so that I can accept it! :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I read the question right, but why do use any constraint on the `path` part? Isn't your aim to have this part unconstrained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match any character but a newline, you can always rely on a greedy dot matching pattern:

```
.*
```

This pattern can match an empty string, so, if you do not want that, replace `*` (that means *zero or more occurrences) with `+` quantifier (meaning *one or more occurrences*).